# A php regex to remove white spaces in html

Tags: php, regex

Hi I have a html like

```
<html>
   <head>
     <title>
          Some title
   </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="one">         some sample info </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I remove white spaces in this html except those in contents and within the tags using some regex using preg_replace? so to get something like this

```
<html><head><title>Some title</title></head><body><div id="one">some sample info</div></body></html>
```

please can anyone help me with this?? :)

Comment: what if there is `<pre>` elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace `(?<=>)\s+(?=<)|(?<=>)\s+(?!=<)|(?!<=>)\s+(?=<)` with empty strings.

**Edit**: There's a simpler form: replace `(?<=>)\s+|\s+(?=<)`

Simply spoken, this regex will replace a group of one or more whitespaces if it has a `>` to the left or a `<` to the right.

It actually has two parts joined by *OR* (symbol: `|`), so either one may match:

1. `(?<=>)\s+` - this will match one or more whitespaces (`\s+` in the regex), if it is preceded by a `<` (in regex: `(?<=>)`).
2. `\s+(?!=<)` - this will match one or more whitespaces if it is followed by a `<` (in regex: `(?!=<)`)

[Learn more](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) about regex.

Comment: This answer is completely unstable and relies on the notion that there are no lingering `>` or `<` symbols in any of the textnodes in the html document.  I would not recommend this technique to anyone.  This is just another case where using regex to do a DOM parser's job is inappropriate.  Researchers, please be informed that regex is "DOM-ignorant" -- it doesn't know if it is matching the start/end of a tag or merely something that resembles the start/end of a tag.  At the very least, this regex is too primitive to do a consistently good job.