# PHP - match spaces not enclosed by HTML tags

Tags: php, regex

I have a text like:

```
Word word word <a href=google.com>word word word</a> word word word
```

I need the positions of spaces, which are not enclosed by any html tag - positions of spaces underlined below:

```
Word_word_word_<a href=google.com>word word word</a>_word_word_word
```

What regex should I use (in `preg_match()`)?

Comment: Might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095447/a-php-regex-to-remove-white-spaces-in-html?rq=1 and the PHP doc will tell you to use option PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE to achieve what you want: http://www.php.net/preg_match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rather straightforward approach:

```
$test = 'Word word word <a href=google.com>word word word</a> word word word';
$t = preg_replace('#\s+((?=.*<a)|(?!.*</a>))#', '_', $test);
var_dump($t); 
// string 'Word_word_word_<a href=google.com>word word word</a>_word_word_word'
```

Obviously, it won't work for the strings that may contain more than one embedded href; for these cases I would suggest another approach: 1) split the string by `<a href...>...</a>` parts, 2) replace all the whitespace in non-linked parts; 3) reconstruct the string.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. There will not be embedded tags in my text.

Comment: I have one more question: how to change it to not match spaces in IMG tags, too? EDIT: ok, i have it: `#\s+((?=.*<a)|(?=.*<img)|(?!.*>))#` :)

Comment: @Siorus If these tags are strictly exclusive in the processed strings, and your HTML is well-formed, replace `<a` and `</a>` with `<img` and `/>` correspondingly in the regex given. Otherwise, you'd better use an HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function:

```
$string = "Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample";
$name = str_replace(' ', '_', $string );
echo $name;
```